# JOIN или multiple select в Mysql

Tags: mysql, select, производительность, join, multiple

Всем привет. Вопрос к знатокам БД касательно производительности. Постараюсь изъясниться понятным языком.

Есть три таблицы: таблица с пользователями, таблица с заказами и таблица с элементами в корзине, каждая из которых относится к какому-то заказу. Соответственно, заказ связан с юзером по UserId, а элемент корзины связан с заказом через OrderId.

У заказа есть несколько предопределённых статусов. Т.е. у пользователя есть много заказов, но в один момент времени он работает только с одним заказом. Для этого есть ещё у юзера такое поле, как CurrentOrderId, чтобы быстро отследить текущий заказ вместо постоянной выборки, типа SELECT Id FROM orders WHERE UserID = target AND Status = 'New'.

Задача стоит в следующем: необходимо достать информацию о заказе имея только UserId.
Я вижу два способа это сделать:

1. Сделать выборку с использованием INNER JOIN.

   SELECT o.Id, o.CompanyId, o.TotalPrice, o.Status, COUNT(*) as ItemCount
   FROM orders as o
   INNER JOIN users as u ON o.Id = u.CurrentOrderId
   INNER JOIN cartitems as i ON o.Id = i.OrderID
   WHERE u.Id = ?
2. Сначала достать запись юзера:

   SELECT CurrentOrderId FROM users WHERE Id = ?

А затем имея на руках CurrentOrderId просто достать нужную мне инфу про заказ без лишнего объединения с таблицей users:

```
SELECT o.Id, o.CompanyId, o.TotalPrice, o.Status, COUNT(*) as ItemCount
FROM orders as o
INNER JOIN cartitems as i ON o.Id = i.OrderID 
WHERE o.Id = ?
```

Вопрос заключается в следующем. Какой из вариантов будет быстрее работать при больших размерах таблиц. Просто закралась мысль, что лишнее объединение при больших объёмах данных будет работать дольше, чем два запроса.

Надеюсь на помощь. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: *закралась мысль, что лишнее объединение при больших объёмах данных будет работать дольше, чем два запроса.* Гони её в шею, пока не добралась до мозга!

Comment: Не надо гадать. Сделайте `explain ваш-первый-запрос` и прикрепите его к вопросу. Там сразу будет видно. Вообще ничего крамольного я в первом варианте не вижу, если сильно сомневаетесь то можете его переписать в виде `ваш-второй-запрос WHERE o.Id=(select CurrentOrderId FROM users WHERE Id = ?)` тогда оптимизатору точно ничего лишнего объединять в голову не придет, он сразу поймет что из users надо взять всего 1 запись